# Second order linear homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients and repeated roots. Why second solution needed?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this case of a second order linear homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients and repeated roots:

$ay'' + by' + cy = 0 $ (and $r1 = r2$)

why is the solution $y_1(t) = e^{-b/2a}$ not enough?
in other words, why do we need a second equation?

Comment: Have you heard the term fundamental set of solutions? See, for example: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HOHomogeneousDE.aspx

Comment: In fact it is enough. Like in some applications they pick up the solution that decay with the time. However, a linear homo. differential equation of order $n$ should have $n$ linearly independent solutions. Check linear operators in linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough because having only the solutions $ce^{r_1t}$ does not
allow you to satisfy all possible initial conditions for both $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$.
You only get the ones where $y'(0)=r_1y(0)$, and this is too restrictive.